# How sensitive is the serial-downvote logic?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

I hardly ever get my questions downvoted, but today I had three questions (from 2009) all downvoted:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/57135/joe?tab=reputation

Should I expect this to get picked up, or is this small enough to get overlooked?

Comment: Either way, you can find out in ~20.25 hours.  At a little after mignight (UTC) tonight, do a [rep recalc](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and see if your rep goes up 6 points.  Howvwer, it may fluctuate more then 6 points (up or down) if there are pending items that the recalc processes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The details of the algorithm aren't public, so I don't think anyone here will be able to tell you for sure if the votes are going to be detected as malicious or not.

That said, with only 3 downvotes... I really wouldn't worry about it either way.

Comment: That last sentence says it all ;)

Comment: But... it's **6 rep**!!! It's gonna take more than a single question upvote to get that rep back :(

Comment: Well, thankfully, people seem to have gone back to focusing on rep instead of flag weight. Oh happy day .. (kinda).

Comment: I guess I wouldn't care so much if I wasn't so close to 10k. :)

Comment: Just to add a point: for a user it might not be a lot of points, but for the answer it might be -> some questoins just have answers with 1 or 2 points, so this "fake" downvote does have an effect on the answer itself?

Comment: @Nanne Potentially, yeah. There's not much that can be done about it. Normally, an answer that's worth upvoting will be upvoted again to offset the stray downvote.

Comment: Agree that there's nothing much to do about it, but it was mostly a reply to the "why should you care about it, only 3 upvotes" sentiment. I agree that for "zOMG teh repz!" it's not a big deal. Ah well, as you say, even for the answers it's not that a big of a deal, but anyway :D